# Add Expatriates.SE as one of the migration options

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Several questions on this website get regularly migrated to [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) or [The Great Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/). Can we have these two options in the flagging pane so that it is easier for the mods and for the users to flag items directly with the relevant issue.

A screenshot of the same will show that the functionality is available for Meta Travel.SE right now, but not for the others.

[image]

Note: I do not mean to ask for this functionality for voting purposes which would result in automatic migration on acquisition of 5 votes, I wish to simply ask for a flag which would notify a moderator regarding the same (in this section specifically) who can then take the decision according to their own discretion.

This would be the similar to the flag type show here, now I don't know how it shows up to the mods, but I believe it would be more suitable in this section instead of where it is currently.

[image]

Comment: This is available only to mods AFAIK.

Comment: @MeNoTalk Not sure I understand what you mean. I'm not a mod. :(

Comment: I meant, only users with diamonds have this, I am sure we asked for it sometime ago but the official reply was that only moderators can do this, normal users can only vote to migrate to meta..

Comment: @MeNoTalk Once again, I'm not a user with a diamond and I took that screenshot. Also note, it's only for flagging the question, not for voting on it.

Comment: I doubt this will come to pass for a long time, as SE appears to no longer link to beta sites. EL&U lost its direct migration to Writers.SE during the closevote revamp, and despite the volume of migrations, has never gotten one to ELL.SE or Linguistics.SE either.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: If you had a diamond, you would have the option you are seeking. That's the point.

Comment: @Flimzy I understand that if I would have been a moderator I could flag the question and it would be migrated and now I understand how the flagging and voting system are somewhat akin to each other. So yeah, I realize now that mods would have an option there whereas we cannot. Odd though. :( Thanks all :)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that migrating to expatriates sounds funny? ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Note: I do not mean to ask for this functionality for voting purposes which would result in automatic migration on acquisition of 5 votes, I wish to simply ask for a flag which would notify a moderator regarding the same (in this section specifically) who can then take the decision according to their own discretion.

In that case, just use a custom flag, and say that you think the question is off topic here but might be suitable for migration to Expatriates. Moderators have the ability to migrate questions to any site in the network, when it is warranted to do so. But migrations to beta sites are strongly discouraged, so don't be too surprised if the question doesn't actually get migrated there.

In practice, if the question isn't going to get migrated to Expatriates anyway, it may be better to use the existing close reason for questions about immigration or moving. That way the question will just get closed here, but the OP will see from the post notice that they may have better luck on Expatriates. One of this site's moderators would have to chime in about what they would prefer you to do.

Comment: I have done that many times, but in this new age of modern technology I believe I should not be required to write Migrate to Expat.SE each time. As far as the actual migration goes, it's my duty to flag them. Whether they actually get migrated is not my task or decision.

Comment: Custom flags? I think you need either 2k or 3k reputation for that.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm not too sure? But I don't recall needing 3k rep for a custom flag.

Comment: @Aditya, SE has said in the past they don't like setting migration paths to non-graduated beta sites as it can drown out the community voice that decides what should be considered on-topic. See [Anna's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/209637).